# GOPATH/GOROOT setup for Hyperledger fabric chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, gopath

I have done basic setup in Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.7 and made all peer's to join the channel. After exploring chaincode in golang, I started trying chaincode install command and I was facing issue's in this step.

**error**

> Error: error getting chaincode code mycc: path to chaincode does not exist: /home/user899/go/src/chaincode

When I just ran `go run chaincode.go`

**error**

> chaincode.go:7:2: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim" in any of:
> /usr/lib/go-1.14/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim (from $GOROOT)
> /home/user899/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim (from $GOPATH)
> chaincode.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer" in any of:
> /usr/lib/go-1.14/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer (from $GOROOT)
> /home/user899/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer (from $GOPATH)

**Environments**

```
echo $GOPATH
/home/user899/go

Chaincode location
/home/user899/SoloNetwork/chaincode
```

Can anyone help.

Thanks

Comment: pass your chaincode path in `peer chaincode install` command with -p flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. Here is the solution, I was not aware of the [directory structure](https://golang.org/doc/code) that need's to be followed in Go.

So first, I checked my GOPATH(usually the workspace where we can write all our go files) using `go env` in the terminal it was located under `home/dev/go`

And coming about the directory structure it should be followed as following :-

$GOPATH + **/src/github.com/chaincode**, So the final structure will be `home/dev/go/src/github.com/chaincode` inside chaincode. I can place all Go files.

So after getting chaincode file from [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go), I have placed in the above location and executed the following commands

- `go mod init`
- `go mod tidy`

Then, I was able to execute peer chaincode install commad

`peer chaincode install -n mycc -p "github.com/chaincode" -v 1.0`

Here in the command `-p "github.com/chaincode"` is the folder name that I have created.

So finally chaincode path is created by these : `$GOPATH + src + -p flag`

If anyone is facing, go binary related issue's set your GOROOT path to the bin location where go is intalled.